# Calvo Price setting in a Multi-sector NK Model

Tags: macroeconomics, new-keynesian-economics

In Calstrom-Fuerst-Ghironi (2004) "Does It Matter (for Equilibrium Determinacy) What Price Index the Central Bank Targets?", they used a standard two-sector NK model, and the optimal price setting condition reads (equation 14):

$\frac{P_{t}^{j}}{P_{t}}=\frac{1}{Z_{t}^{j}}\frac{W_{t}^{j}}{P_{t}}$,

where $P_{t}^{j}$ is the price index for sector j, $P_{t}$ is aggregate price level, $W_{t}^{j}$  is wage for sector j, $Z_{t}^{j}$  is the marginal cost in sector j, so that $1/{Z_{t}^{j}}$ is the markup of price over marginal cost.

I do not understand how this equation is derived. My understanding is that in multi-sector models we still have pricing equation to be in the form of $P_{t}^{j}=\frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon-1}\frac{E_{t}[\cdots]}{E_{t}[\cdots]}$.

The equation in Calstrom-Fuerst-Ghironi (2004) also showed up in another paper of theirs using multi-sector NK model. In both papers, they say refer to Yun (1996), but I do not see a form like this in Yun (1996).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: In particular, isn't nominal marginal cost just $W_{t}^{j}$ (their production technology is $Y_{t}^{j} = L_{t}^{j}$).

Comment: Could you please include hyperlinks to those papers?

Comment: My bad, their two papers are linked below:
http://faculty.washington.edu/ghiro/CaFuGhiroJET0506.pdf

http://faculty.washington.edu/ghiro/CaFuGhiroHeRelPrices082206.pdf